# Valid asset_pair for Kraken.com

Tags: api, kraken

Im trying to utilize Kraken's [API](https://www.kraken.com/help/api).
I'm looking for a list of supported `asset_pair`.

**Example:** `query_public('Ticker', {'pair': 'XETHZEUR'})` will return ticker info for ethereum in relation to euros. The asset pair in this example is `XETHZEUR`.

Does anyone have access to such a list?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the list is found here:
https://api.kraken.com/0/public/AssetPairs

Also here's a list of assets:
https://api.kraken.com/0/public/Assets